# Defining Absolute Function in Set Notation

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, definition, absolute-value

I am trying to define the Absolute function in set notation. 
$$
|x|=
\begin{cases}
x, \text{ if x $\ge$ 0} \\
-x, \text{   if x $<$ 0}
\end{cases}
$$

Here are my two attempts:
$$f_1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R \times R}: (x\ge0\implies y=x)  \land  (x<0\implies y=-x)\}$$
$$f_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R \times R}: (x\ge0\land y=x)  \lor  (x<0\land y=-x)\}$$

The first attempt is restating the definition but in set notation.

**The set written should be ONLY one set. No unions are allowed.**

Questions:

1) Which definition is correct(or both are wrong) ? Explain why.

2) Is there any mechanical way for writing functions in set notation given their cases ?

3) Assuming one of the above are correct how can I prove that it is a function ? If none are correct then provide correct one with explanation.

4) I am not sure but I think $f_1=f_2$. Is that right ?

Comment: I would write $$\{(x,x)\mid x\in \mathbb R, x\ge 0\}\cup\{(-x,x)\mid x\in\mathbb R, x \ge 0 \}$$

Comment: @HenningMakholm I wrote it that way first. But I am trying to have it all in one set notation not two sets.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility could be $\;\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+ \mid x^2 = y^2\}\;$.